# Converting raster layer from EPSG:3003 to EPSG:4326

Tags: raster, resampling

I am working with two type of raster layers:

- The first one is a `.tif` file downloaded from [Worlclim database](https://www.worldclim.org/data/index.html) that is in WGS84 (EPSG:4326) coordinates reference system. So that, the resolution is expressed 2.5 arc minutes.
- On the other hand, I have a [Corine Land Cover](https://land.copernicus.eu/pan-european/corine-land-cover) raster file `.tif` that is in EPSG:3003 and have a resolution expressed in meter (100m).

I would like to transform the Corine Land Cover raster in WGS84 with the same resolution of the Wordlclim raster file.

How could I do?

I have tried to export the Corine file changing its coordinate reference system and resample the obtained raster but the dimension of pixel isn't regular (x,-y).

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: This can be accomplished simply with the terra package in rstats. If you can give us some clue on software that you use (e.g. ArcGIS, QGIS, rstats, Python), then an answer can be provided. There are numerous ways to achieve your goal.